# Android ViewModel With Switch Cases is not working?

Tags: android, switch-statement, viewmodel, android-databinding, android-livedata

Precisely, it is working but ViewModel is firing all the cases instead of selected case.

If I set the value enablethis to "one" or something else, it will not have any effect on it. Ideally, if I set enablethis to any of these [one,two,..], it should enable that case only and set the value of pressed to "true" from that case only. But that's not happening.

What I have figured it out that the all observers are observing any change in the values even though they are inside switch case and causing pressed=true. How can I avoid that.

```
switch (enablethis) {
    case "four":
        messageViewModel.getMessageOne().observe((LifecycleOwner) ctx, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
                if (integer > 0)  pressed = true;
                Log.d("message one","one : "+integer);
            }
        });
        break;
    case "two":
        messageViewModel.getMessageTwo().observe((LifecycleOwner) ctx, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
                if (integer > 0)  pressed = true;
                Log.d("message two","two : "+integer);
            }
        });
        break;
    case "two":
        messageViewModel.getMessageThree().observe((LifecycleOwner) ctx, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
                if (integer > 0)  pressed = true;
                Log.d("message three","three : "+integer);
            }
        });
        break;
    case "three":
        messageViewModel.getMessageFour().observe((LifecycleOwner) ctx, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
                if (integer > 0)  pressed = true;
                Log.d("message four","four : "+integer);
            }
        });
        break;
    case "four":
        messageViewModel.getMessageFive().observe((LifecycleOwner) ctx, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
                if (integer > 0)  pressed = true;
                Log.d("message five","five : "+integer);
            }
        });
        break; 
}
```

I have also tried doing this but that's not working either -

```
messageViewModel.getMessageFive().observe((LifecycleOwner) ctx, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
                if (integer > 0 && enablethis.equals("five")) pressed = true;
            }
        });
```

**Solution suggested and **updated** by @JeelVankhede still not working -**

```
    messageViewModel.getMessageFive().observe((LifecycleOwner) ctx, new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
            if (integer > 0) pressed = true;
        }
    });
 messageViewModel.getMessageOne().removeObserver(this);
 messageViewModel.getMessageTwo().removeObserver(this);
 messageViewModel.getMessageThree().removeObserver(this);
 messageViewModel.getMessageFour().removeObserver(this);
 // messageViewModel.getMessageFive().removeObserver(this);
```

Comment: You'll need to remove other observers in particular case like `messageViewModel.getMessageFour().removeObservers(this)`.

Comment: @JeelVankhedeThanks for your reply. How can re register observers once remove. I am asking this because those values(switch cases) are going to get selected through out the usage of apps, multiple times.

Comment: Let's say you've **case "four"** in which you're observing **livedata one**, at that time you can **remove other observes** (livedata two, three etc.) using above syntax i provided.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Please check my updated post. Let me know two things - 1. Am I removing observers correctly? 2. Once I used all the cases in the switch and go back to any of them, somehow I start getting values from all the observers again.

Comment: Use like this `messageViewModel.getMessageFive().observe();` then remove observer after that syntax `messageViewModel.getMessageFive().observe();
 messageViewModel.getMessageOne().removeObserver(this);`

Comment: Not inside the observer.

Comment: @JeelVankhedeThanks for your patience, When I remove the other observers out the observer, I get an error passing "this" in removeObserver(this).   **removeObserver
(android.arch.lifecycle.Observer<java.lang.Integer>)
in LiveData cannot be applied .... *

Comment: Where did you initialize these observers? It looks like the switch is not needed, because each of these observers are different from each other, each of them will only emit values when the value from the source changes. IMO, if the switch is needed, it should be in the place where the value gets updated/changed. Any reason there is a switch for these observers?

Comment: You can use same `ctx` object for that **this** variable.

Comment: with ctx I am getting this -  **                removeObserver
(android.arch.lifecycle.Observer<java.lang.Integer>)
in LiveData cannot be applied
to
(android.content.Context
**
---------------
So I did this --  messageViewModel.getMessageOne().removeObserver((Observer<Integer>) ctx) but app is keep crashing

Comment: @JeelVankhede can you please reply ?

Comment: @s-hunter hahaha ...that was a good one. I did it. I am so stupid.